# What's the minimum age to join Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, users

I just saw the profile of a [user that's 14 years old](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001736/amit-joki) on SO and I'm wondering...

What's the minimum age to join Stack Overflow?

Comment: Related: [How do I use Stack Exchange if I'm under 13 years old?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The minimum age to participate is 13 (or 16 when located in the European Union), as stated [in the TOS under section 3, "Age Eligibility"](https://stackexchange.com/legal).

> You must be at least 13 years old to access or use the Network or
> Services, including without limitation to complete a Stack Overflow
> account registration. By accessing or using the Services or the
> Network in any manner, you represent and warrant that you are at least
> 13 years of age. If you are under 13 years old, you may not, under any
> circumstances or for any reason, access or use the Services or Network
> in any manner, and may not provide any personal information to or on
> the Services or Network (including, for example, a name, address,
> telephone number or email address).
>
> If you are located within the European Union, you must be at least 16
> years old to access or use the Network or Services, including without
> limitation to complete a Stack Overflow Account Registration. By
> accessing or using the Services or the Network in any manner, you
> represent and warrant that you are at least 16 years of age. If you
> are under 16 years old, you may not, under any circumstances or for
> any reason, access or use the Services or Network in any manner, and
> may not provide any personal information to or on the Services or
> Network (including, for example, a name, address, telephone number or
> email address).

Comment: Tks for the link, but what's written there is: `...No one under the age of 13 may provide any personal information...`, this doesn't mean they cannot join and post on SO.

Comment: *"Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual ... at least 13 years of age."*

Comment: I think the TOS are ambiguous about this.

Comment: What is ambiguous about it @Tuga? Seems pretty clear. Let's put it like this: all accounts I've seen of users younger than 13 were nuked on sight.

Comment: What I read there is that anyone, even a 5 y/o kid, can post at SO.

Comment: Even a dog could technically. But show me where it states explicitly that users of 12 or under can and are allowed to participate.

Comment: It doesn't state that but also doesn't state the opposite, that's why it's ambiguous.

Comment: I have quoted you the opposite.

Comment: @Tuga: The *US law* sees you as giving out personally identifiable information, and states that if a site takes that info and stores it *you **must** be 13 years or older* or have your parents explicit consent. Stack Exchange doesn't want to meet the requirements for parental consent verification, so it states you need to be 13 or older to use the site.

Comment: @Tuga: The wording is **very clear** on this. You have to be at least 13 years of age. If Stack Exchange employees or moderators find an account that clearly shows they are younger they **will delete that account**.

Comment: Corollary: if someone under the age of 13 joins, but provides no evidence to support the fact that he is under 13, he can stay. there is just no age verification. (and even if he were still not allowed to participate... how would you enforce that rule?)

Comment: @Michael As with most TOS, age is almost impossible to prove, but the write-up legally covers the site owner(s).

Comment: Also, I don't see the issue with clarity, here. The first sentence is crystal clear that in order to Subscribe, the user must be at least 13.

Comment: What is should happen If my kid under 13 want to join Stackoverflow? @Bart

Comment: They will have to wait. Or you can ask questions on their behalf.

Comment: The new wording seems even more clear.