# Can a user be greeted on his birthday?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, notifications

Can Stack Overflow greet a person on his birthday?

I understand, this is not Google or a social networking site like Facebook, but a feature like this can really please the users.

I like the way my user home page shows how many days I have visited the site consecutively.
Similarly it would be a pleasure to see how many birthdays I had celebrated as a member of Stack Overflow.

Also, it would be nice to receive a greeting or notification from Stack Overflow moderators, on our birthday. I don't think it is hard to implement either.

Comment: I don't think it would add any value to have a birthday greeting on SO. But for what it's worth, congratulations on having 3 or 4 birthdays whilst being a member of the site.

Comment: Why would this be pleasing? I'm not impressed that software can track my birthday and compare it to the current date. `if` statements lost all their magic *years* ago.

Comment: @CodyGray I wished that StackOverflow can provide a field for entering user's birthday in his profile, so that it can be tracked every year.

Comment: @shasi - there are other reasons for having someone's date of birth other than sending "Happy Birthday" messages.

Comment: @ChrisF What is it used for on SO other than displaying a user's age on their profile?

Comment: @Bojangles - that's one use.

Comment: Oh my God, i did not expect these many down votes. Else i would have not asked this lame question. Can someone delete it please?

Comment: A field *is* provided for entering your birthday. There is just no logic to wish you a happy birthday. I'm saying I see no point in such a feature.

Comment: @shasi [Voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: sashi, I think it's a good thing actually, as you can proudly say *"I'm **the one** who asked about birthdays and got declined!"* ;)

Comment: The user's age is used to determine [the minimum age to be an eligible SO user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251324/2982225)

Comment: I'm really pleased when a site doesn't feel entitled to know my birthday. I typically fill in Januari 1st, with the direct effect that I get congratulated a lot around that date. _Morons_. Mind your own business, please :)

Answer (score 17):

Please no! I know when my birthday is, I have my friends to greet me for it (and a plethora of annoying websites that send me emails "greeting" me).

If anything, I would not mind seeing "anniversaries" of really great questions, but since there aren't that many of them, I can just sort by votes and find them easily.

Comment: I remember when I had a Facebook account years ago when it was first available to university students. I made the mistake of entering my birthday, and then when my birthday rolled around, I got literally *overwhelmed* with people I barely knew wishing me a happy birthday. People that would otherwise have no idea when my birthday was. It wasn't particularly warm or friendly, just sort of annoying. And even less appropriate on a Q&A site.

Comment: +1 for the great question/answer anniversary idea.  It's always fun re-reading old, in-depth discussions.

Answer (score 13):

I hesitate to mark this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) straight away, but I can't see this ever being implemented.

The focus of the site has been and will always be the questions and answers and NOT the users.

Answer (score 10):

Uh, hello. Greetings are provided to you on your birthday in the form of the [yearling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling).

See, I'm [3 years old](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=790387) :)

Comment: To my surprise, today i earned [3 Yearling badges on Meta StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=386579). And the shocking thing is that all are awarded 1 hour ago!

Answer (score 3):

Today is my birthday and I was unable to get the day off work. Upon visiting Stack Overflow I was surprised to *not* see some form of birthday message in the notification bar.

Ignoring the part about seeing how may birthdays you've celebrated here; this is an interesting question in that here on Stack Overflow's Meta this has 27 down votes and 6 up votes, yet on Stack Exchange's Meta [the question of a birthday greeting asked over 4 years beforehand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47718/display-a-happy-birthday-message-when-a-user-logs-in-on-their-birthday) has received 71 up votes and only 19 down votes. Quite a difference, unless everyone is only focusing on the count part of the question.

With the new notification system in place, I don't see any reason something like this would be all that obtrusive or annoying:

[image: Example Image]

I mean, I'm sure some setting could be added for those of you who would rather not see a friendly message like this.